# Replicate files in Azure Storage account across regions

Tags: azure-storage

I have a storage account in Azure in Australia. I wish to access the files in the file storage associated with this storage account in Thailand.

What is the best way to achieve this? Do I create a separate storage account and then replicate it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, you could access the files from anywhere.

Refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction):

> - Accessible. **Data in Azure Storage is accessible from anywhere in the world over HTTP or HTTPS**. Microsoft provides SDKs for Azure Storage in a variety of languages -- .NET, Java, Node.js, Python, PHP, Ruby, Go, and others -- as well as a mature REST API. Azure Storage supports scripting in Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI. And the Azure portal and Azure Storage Explorer offer easy visual solutions for working with your data.

Besides, if you want to replicate the files, you could use [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy#copy-files-in-file-storage) to do it.

Comment: I want to mount it a drive. When I give the net use command from command prompt it runs the command but I do not see the drive

Comment: I suppose that you want to map network drive, you could refer to this [article](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/map-network-drive-to-azure-storage-account-file-storage/).